# Clojure - (read-string String calling function

Tags: clojure, resolve

I've got the following in a clojure file:

```
(ns helloworld
  (:gen-class
    :main -main))

(defn hello-world-fn []
  (println "Hello World"))

(defn -main [& args]
  (eval (read-string "(hello-world-fn)")))
```

and I'm running it with

```
lein run helloworld
```

and I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol:
 helloworld in this context, compiling:(helloworld.clj:12)
```

I have a feeling I need to do something with `ns-resolve` or `resolve` but I haven't had any success. I've tried the following in the main function:

```
(let [call-string  (read-string "(hello-world-fn)")
      func (resolve  (symbol (first call-string)))
      args (rest call-string)]
   (apply func args))
```

Without success.

Can someone (a) point me in the right direction; and (b) explain precisely what is going on in the Clojure reader when this occurs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve your challenge, in a very elegant way, using `macros`. In fact, you can write a macro that mimics `eval`.

```
(defmacro my-eval [s] `~(read-string s))
(my-eval "(hello-world-fn)")); "Hello World"
```

It works better that `eval` because the symbol resolution of `s` occurs in the context that calls `my-eval`. Thanks to @Matthias Benkard for the clarifications.

You can read about macros and their syntax in http://clojure.org/reader

Comment: Why does this solve the namespace issue automatically when ns-resolve doesn't?

Comment: @hawkeye Because `resolve` works at run-time and will resolve symbols within the *current namespace*, which is whatever the `*ns*` variable is pointing to at the time, whereas macro-expanded code within the context of a file is processed by the file compiler, which resolves symbols according to the namespace declarations within the file.

Comment: Thanks - so if `*ns*` is already pointing to helloworld in the example about - why doesn't it `resolve` the function?

Comment: @hawkeye You need to distinguish strictly between run-time and compile-time. At compile-time, the namespace something is being compiled within is known, but after compilation, the code is fully resolved and namespace-qualified, and thus independent of the run-time *current namespace*. Code passed to `eval` is resolved based on the `*ns*` variable *at that point in time*, that is, at run-time, not at compile-time. The `*ns*` variable doesn't magically change when you call a function compiled within another namespace (that would be pretty weird behavior, IMHO). You have to bind `*ns*` manually.

Comment: Much more elegant and flexible. Really like the explanations from @MatthiasBenkard as well.

Answer (score 6):

Try to see what the actual namespace is inside your `-main`.

```
(defn -main [& args]
  (prn *ns*)
  (eval (read-string "(hello-world-fn)")))
```

It outputs `#<Namespace user>` before bombing out with the exception. This hints that execution of programs with `lein run` starts out in the `user` namespace, which obviously does not contain the mapping for your `hello-world-fn` symbol. You'll need to explicitly qualify it.

```
(defn -main [& args]
  (eval (read-string "(helloworld/hello-world-fn)")))
```

Comment: When calling `(hello-world-fn)` directly, it works. Why does it behave different than `eval`?

Comment: @YehonathanSharvit Because the symbol `hello-world-fn` will be resolved at compile-time in that case, so the namespace declaration near the top the source file is relevant.  `"(hello-world-fn)"`, on the other hand, is just a string.  The compiler does not look into strings to namespace-qualify them, because it would be wrong to do so; therefore, `eval`, which runs at run-time, needs to resolve name references by looking at the `*ns*` variable when executed.

Comment: Really like the debugging approach and solving it directly. I thought the other one was more out of the box and more elegant. Appreciate @MatthiasBenkard explaining the compile phases.