# Clojure riddle: eval, macros and namespaces

Tags: macros, clojure, eval

In clojure, macros give a tremendous power to the programmer. `eval` also is very powerful. There exist some subtle differences between the two. I hope that this riddle will shine some light on this topic.

```
(ns hello)
(defmacro my-eval [x] `~(read-string x))
(defn hello[] "Hello")
(defn run-stuff []
  (println (hello))
  (println (my-eval "(hello)"))
  (println (eval (read-string "(hello)"))))
(ns main)
(try (hello/run-stuff)
  (catch Exception e (println e)))
```

Over the 3 statements inside `run-stuff` body, which one causes an exception and why the other ones don't?

I have formulated the following riddle following the investigation of this beautiful question [Clojure - (read-string String calling function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9159268/813665). Thanks to @Matthias Benkard for the clarifications

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(println (hello))` and `(println (my-eval "(hello)"))` are completely identical statements -- the only difference is that one will confuse your editor more.  `my-eval` is NOT comparable to the real `eval`.  The difference is that the argument to `my-eval` needs to be a string at compile time -- the following errors out because the symbol `x` can't be cast to a string.

```
(def x "(hello)")
(my-eval x)
```

This makes `my-eval` utterly pointless - you can "eval" a literal string or you can remove the quotes and the `my-eval` and have equally functional code (that your editor will understand).

Real `eval`, on the other hand, tries to compile code at run time.  Here, it fails because it is being run from the `main` namespace, not the `hello` namespace, as @Matthias Benkard pointed out.